# Dependent dropdown list in yii returns empty string even after validation

Tags: php, yii

I know this question might be familiar to most of you, but allow me to ask because most of the answers to related questions here in this forum and in YII forum have not been given a satisfactory answer. My two depended drop downs are working fine and the 2nd one gets populated based on the selection of the first one. All values are from the database. 
Now my problem is that, the second dropdown keeps on returning an empty value even after a value is selected and it doesn't seem to be validated. I have searched through the forums but none of them seem well tackled. Pliz help me out. This very important to me.

EDITED:
I am sorry, I had assumed that its sth that u already know but here is my code:
_form.php

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($users,'country_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($users,'country_id',CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(
                array('order' => 'country')),'country_id','country'),
                array(
                    'class'=>'form-control',
                    'prompt'=>'Choose Your Country',
                    'ajax'=>array(
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'url' => CController::createUrl('users/findcity'),
                        'data'=> array('country_id'=>'js:this.value'),
                        'update'=>'#city_id'))
            );?> 
    <?php echo $form->error($users,'country_id'); ?>
</div>

    <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($address,'city_id'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array(),
                array('prompt'=>'Choose Your City','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($address,'city_id'); ?>
</div>
```

And here is my controller function that find the cities associated with the choosen country

```
public function actionFindcity()
    {
        $data = City::model()->findAll('country_id=:country_id',
                                array(':country_id'=>$_POST['country_id']));
        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'city_id','name');

        echo "<option value=''>City</option>";
        foreach($data as $value=>$name)
            echo CHtml::tag('option', array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
```

I have tried many ways but I cant seem to figure out where the problem is, tho am doubting these line of code coz I cant seem to find the model that responds to this code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('city_id','', array(),
                array('prompt'=>'Choose Your City','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks @RafayZiaMir, I have edited my code with the appropriate code.

Comment: write CVarDumper::Dump($_POST,100,true);die(); in your controller action. and see in the firebug what it returns

Comment: and to see how you can check the response, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495749/yii-frameworrk-ajax-link/21497212#21497212

Answer (score 0):

hers the solution

in **my _Form**

```
 <?php  if(isset($_POST['your_Model']['country'])) 
                                {$countryid = $_POST['your_Model']['country'];}
                                else {$countryid = ''; }?>
                        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'country',
                            CHtml::listData(Country::model()->findAll(), 'country_id', 'country'),
                            array(
                            'ajax' => array(
                            'type'=>'POST', //request type
                            'url'=>CController::createUrl('your_Model/dynamicStates'), //url to call.
                            'update'=>'#'.CHtml::activeId($model,'state'),
                             array('class'=>'ajaxlink'),
                            ),'prompt'=>'--select--',)
                             ); ?>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'state'); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         <?php $listStates = array();
                            if(!empty($countryid)) 
                                {
                                    $listStates = $this->getStatesList($countryid);            
                                }   
                            if ($model->state != '') 
                                {
                                    $listStates = $this->getStatesList($model->country);    
                                }
                            ?>
                        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'state',$listStates, array('empty'=>'--select--')); ?>
```

**and in controller or model**

```
        public function actionDynamicStates(){


    $data = $this->getStatesList($_POST['your_Model']['country']);
    foreach($data as $value=>$name)
    {
        echo CHtml::tag('option',
        array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
    }
}

public function getStatesList($country_id) {
    $data=State::model()->findAll('country_id=:id',
    array(':id'=>(int)$country_id));
    return CHtml::listData($data,'state_id','state');
}
```

Hope this Helps You If You want I Can Explain You

Comment: Thanks @sandeep, Let me try out your code n give u a feedback soon.

Comment: If their is any different Solution please let me know

Comment: hello sandeep, I tried out your code but didnt seem to work out. I also tried to post my altered code for you to check out but this forum couldnt allow me, so I had to look for another soln n I found this page which worked well for me: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cascadedropdown/

Comment: ok you used extension no problem.. you can edit your question any ways  you got solution. thanks