# dropdownlist onchange using ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, dropdownlistfor

i have a dropdownlist

modelA

```
 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'type'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'type',array('empty'=>'choose refertype','1'=>'typeA','2'=>'typeB','3'=>'typeC')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'type'); ?>
```

following is  my ajax code what it must do is when i select typeA or any other type it must fetch data from db (depending on the type of modelA data from db of modelB must be fetched )and display in #showdata div which is not working when

```
$('#modelname_type').change(function(){

    if($('#modelname_type').val() == '1'){
        $('#showdata').show();
        $.ajax(
            'url':'Yii::app()->createUrl('controllerB/actionB')',
            'type':'get',
            'data':array('id'=>$_GET['id']),
            'success': function(res){       
                $("#showdata").html(res);
            }       
        );          
        $('#codea').hide();     
    }   
});
```

works only for

```
$('#modelname_type').change(function(){

    if($('#modelname_type').val() == '1'){
        $('#showdata').show();          
        $('#codea').hide();     
    }
});
```

Please let me know where am i going wrong please am really stuck from past week am not that strong with ajax

Comment: Javascript doesn't execute `Yii::app()->createUrl('controllerB/actionB')'` as it's php function.

Comment: And `'data':array('id'=>$_GET['id'])` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here

```
 if($('#modelname_type').val() == '1'){
```

change to

```
  var mtype =$('#modelname_type').val();
    if(mtype == '1'){
```

IN AJAX THE

`url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/controllerB/actionB/id/"+str';`

Will work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Proper use of ajax call in jQuery is:

```
$.ajax(
    'url': 'your_script.php',
    'type': 'get',
    'data': array,
    'success': function (res) {
         $("#showdata").html(res);
    }
});
```

where `array` is a javascript array.

Your code doesn't work, because url and data are not proper. Javascript won't execute PHP code.

Here are tutorials you may find useful:

- [php4every1](http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/)
- [cleverweb](http://www.cleverweb.nl/php/jquery-ajax-call-tutorial/)

Comment: not working 'your_script.php' in modelB' viewB and ajax call is in modelA'viewA as its all in yii  d4 ws calling dt way .what bout data: array i need to pass the query string which is in the url

Comment: It's just a scheme. When called a GET request with data as in `array` is send to script `yours_script.php`. That's (simplified) how ajax call works and how you should use it. Now your task is to use this knowledge to modify your code. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: for anchor tag it works dropdownlist it doesnt  .modelB's viewB and ajax call is in modelA'viewA wherein modelB's viewB is to be displayed

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Mind that I've only pointed out what's wrong with your code, I'm not gonna write it for you.

Comment: l write it dont worry :) but then let me know y is it not working and link or guidance u can provide

Comment: thanks michal :) i used javacsript style ajax and not jquery ajax ....this works :) ..i.e., ......... xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/controllerB/actionB/id/"+str,true);

Comment: thanks michal :) i used javacsript style ajax and not jquery ajax ....this works :) ..i.e., ......... xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/controllerB/actionB/id/"+str,true);...this takes the php url whereas jquery ajax doesnt strange :D .... yet bth r ajax :) i dont know wts wrong can anyone please y so?

Comment: Javascript code generated by PHP script? It won't work otherwise. Try using firebug console to track where ajax call is really sent.

Comment: nope m using the php link code in xmlhttp . i do checkout infirebug andlet u know :)

Comment: url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/controllerB/actionB/id/"+str'; work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

For Dependent Dropdown list 
You can Check This [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169219/3012139) contains based on country , specific states populated on other dropdown list..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169219/3012139

Comment: thanks sandeep :) my query was not of deppendent dropdown rather was a popup onchange for dropdown ..... and i did get the soln xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl;?>/index.php/controllerB/actionB/id/"+str,true);